# Disable button unless min-length of textarea is reached - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a textarea and a button, I want to disable the button until the textarea has reached the min-length.

I thought about something similar to this code:

[JsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/K5Pfj/285/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
$('input[type="text"],textarea').on('keyup',function() {
    var textarea_value = $("#texta").val();
 
    if(textarea_value != '') {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
    }else{
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea maxlength="20" minlength="5" rows="4" cols="30" id="texta"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="next" />
```

I tried changing the `.val` to `.minlength` and tested it like this:

```
 if(textarea_value < '5') {    
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
 }else{
     $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
 }
```

but it did not work.

Anyone has an idea how to check if minlength of textarea is reached ? With pure javascript or jquery ?

Comment: Please do not misuse formatting. Keep blockquotes for quoting. Welcome to [so].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a certain attribute from a HTML element using jQuery, you would use the `.attr()` method:

> Gets the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.

reference: [api.jquery.com/attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

**Here is the code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);

$('textarea').on('keyup',function()
{
    var textarea_val = $("#texta").val();
 
    var minLength = $("#texta").attr( 'minlength' );
 
    if(textarea_val != '' && textarea_val.length >= minLength)
    {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
    }
    else
    {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea maxlength="20" minlength="5" rows="4" cols="30" id="texta"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="next" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself, it is a little bit different, means it does not check the minlength, it does check the words that are written.

Here is the
[FiddleJS](http://fiddle.jshell.net/K5Pfj/286/)

The code should be self explaining.

```js
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
    $('input[type="text"],textarea').on('keyup',function() {
    s = document.getElementById("texta").value;
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,"");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    if (s.split(' ').length >= 3) {
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , false);
    }
    else{
        $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled' , true);
    }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea maxlength="20" minlength="5" rows="4" cols="30" id="texta"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="next" />
```